# Hiding youtube sidebar when specific class exists with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

On youtube to the right of a video there's a suggestion list. For a long time I've used this css to hide it when not mouse hovering above it:

```
#watch7-sidebar, .watch-sidebar, #related {
    opacity: 0;
}

#watch7-sidebar::hover, .watch-sidebar:hover, #related:hover  {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Recently I wrote a script to add a toggle button to disable the hover if toggle button is on. The button toggles a class (.perma-hidden) on #watch7-sidebar.

I've tried this css and the commented out lines:

```
#watch7-sidebar {
    display: none;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    /*pointer-events: none;*/
    opacity: 0;
}

#watch7-sidebar:hover:not(.perma-hidden) {
    display: block;
    /*visibility: visible;*/
    /*pointer-events: auto;*/
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I can see why it doesn't work but can't figure out a solution that do work. That is; suggestion list will be visible if mouse hover over it unless the class .perma-hidden is present.

Just hiding the suggestion list isn't enough, you can still click on the list entries.

Comment: May I see your whole code..? example picture, HTML, CSS, JS, etc..

Comment: @YoungKyunJin 
I solved it. For your interest, instructions above.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Solution by OP.*

I figured it out. Forgot about css's ordering priority.
Here's the instructions for those interested.
Using Stylebot [0] to apply the css and Tampermonkey [1] to run the script that adds the toggle button next to the subscription button.

[0] https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha
[1] https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

For Stylebot the css:

```
#watch7-sidebar {
    opacity: 0;
}

#watch7-sidebar.perma-hidden {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

#watch7-sidebar:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

For Tampermonkey the userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube - perma-hidden
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    // TODO: save state.
    function appendSwitch() {
        var ws_container = document.getElementById('watch7-subscription-container');

        var span_tag = document.createElement('span'); // Toggle
        span_tag.className = 'yt-uix-checkbox-on-off';

        var span_input_tag = document.createElement('input');
        span_input_tag.id = 'suggestion-list-checkbox';
        span_input_tag.type = 'checkbox';

        var span_label_tag = document.createElement('label');
        span_label_tag.for = 'suggestion-list-checkbox';
        span_label_tag.id = 'suggestion-list-checkbox-label';

        var span_label_span_checked_tag = document.createElement('span');
        span_label_span_checked_tag.className = 'checked';

        var span_label_span_toggle_tag = document.createElement('span');
        span_label_span_toggle_tag.className = 'toggle';

        var span_label_span_unchecked_tag = document.createElement('span');
        span_label_span_unchecked_tag.className = 'unchecked';

        span_label_tag.appendChild(span_label_span_checked_tag);
        span_label_tag.appendChild(span_label_span_toggle_tag);
        span_label_tag.appendChild(span_label_span_unchecked_tag);

        span_tag.appendChild(span_input_tag);
        span_tag.appendChild(span_label_tag);
        ws_container.appendChild(span_tag);

        span_input_tag.addEventListener('click', toggleSwitch);
    }

    function toggleSwitch() {
        let suggestion_list = document.querySelector('#watch7-sidebar');
        if (suggestion_list) {
            suggestion_list.classList.toggle('perma-hidden');
        }
    }

    function waitForElementId(elementId, callBack) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            if (element) {
                callBack(elementId, element);
            } else {
                waitForElementId(elementId, callBack);
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    waitForElementId('watch7-subscription-container', function() {
        appendSwitch();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best CSS, but I think it should work. You first set the behavior regarding the mouse hover, then you override it when .perma-hidden is set.

```
#watch7-sidebar:hover {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

#watch7-sidebar.perma-hidden:hover {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that suggestion didn't work however I figured it out myself after some much needed sleep and relaxation. If you're interested, scroll up.